# restricting ASP.net dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to restrict the content of some dropdown boxes in ASP.NET.

There are 6 dropdowns on the page, and the dropdown items get populated from the database.

In the database, the dropdown table is like this:

```
ID    Text
1     This is some text
2     Some more text
3     Even more text
4     This is just silly now
```

So for each textbox on the webpage - I want to display only certain database table rows.

For example, for dropdownbox1 I might want to display table IDs 1 and 2.
For dropdownbox2 I might want to display table IDs 2 and 3.
For dropdownbox3 I might want to display only row 4.

So without hardcoding this in LINQ, would I be better creating another table for each dropdown box, and what IDs I want to display?
I'm not sure whats the best approach?

Comment: is there any particular pattern or it is random?

Comment: What is so difficult in writing `...WHERE ID IN(1,2)` or `IN(2,3)`? Just use different datasources for each dropdown. If it's LINQ: `.Where(x => new[]{1,2}.Contains(x.ID))`. Yes, hardcoding is the best approach. If the dropdowns actually represent different type of entities you should refactor your datamodel by creating other tables with meaningful names. But it's impossible to suggest something with this anonymous sample-data.

Comment: Basically the requirements have changed, at the minute every textbox on the page displays ALL the rows from the table.  But now they want certain textboxes to contain certain rows.  It could change at some point what text will get displayed.

Comment: Add a new column to the table to discriminate which rows belong with which ddl.

Comment: I would only advise creating a dropdown config table with the ddl id and what is to be displayed if it will change or even more so if you want the user to change via some kind of admin portal, otherwise hardcode it.

Comment: if I add a new column, since one row can be used for more than one ddl - could I have to comma separate them in the new column?  So for row 1 it would have ddl1,ddl2 - would it be better to have in a new table somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think opening a new table requires too much effort for such a simple task. Of course it's up to your development/design style, but I recommend adding a new column to your present table and hold dropdown list IDs within it.

**Solution 1:**

```
ID    Text                       Dropdowns
1     This is some text          -DD1-DD2-
2     Some more text             -DD2-DD3-
3     Even more text             -DD3-
4     This is just silly now     -DD4-
```

You can populate the dropdowns with a slight change in the code. The reason I used separators is to handle situations like looking for `DD1` succeeds in the text `DD10`.

You will have to use `-DropdownID-` (or any separator you choose to use with the same format) for string containment search. Editing the value within that column, assuming `-` is the separator:

- Assign `-` as default value of the column in the database side and columns will hold `-` if they're empty.
- Adding a new dropdown ID, first look for your ID is contained, than concatenate `DropdownID-` to column value.
- Deleting a dropdown ID, just replace `DropdownID-` with empty string: `""`.
- As told before, use `-DropdownID-` for search.

If every entity can only be shown in one dropdown at once, you can just simply write dropdown's name to the new column and look for equality instead of containment.

**Solution 2:**

I see that you thought about opening new database tables for each dropdown list. It's a very bad approach. You can build something like:

```
     -- Texts--                     -- Dropdowns --          -- DropdownTexts --
ID    Text                       ID     ViewID   >..<    ID     TextID     DropdownID
1     This is some text          1       DD1             1       1            1
2     Some more text             2       DD2             2       1            3
3     Even more text             3       DD3             3       2            3
4     This is just silly now                             4       4            1
```

I opened the table `Dropdowns` in case you need database side help with your implementation, you can add more columns to `Dropdowns` to make it more configurable. If you don't, ignore `Dropdowns` table and directly write the `DropdownID` in your `View` to `DropdownID` in `DropdownTexts` table.

Comment: this seems smart - assumming the .Contains works ok which you have accounted for.  I'll try it out but this could be a good intermediate solution rather than hardcoding or creating a new table..

Comment: please see my edit. I don't know how further I can dig this, really :)